# get all words without html tags with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace, regex-negation

i try to use an regex expression to get all words without html tags
the goal of this is to tag all words with span tags to be capable to get the word when my mouse is over, but keep html initial tags

for example this code

```
<p>hello i'm <b>jesus</b></p>
```

should become

```
<p><span>hello</span> <span>i'm</span><b><span>jesus<span></b></p>
```

So, first step for me, is to get all words, without html tags, and then replace it with span

This is my regex in javascript
    ([^\r\n\t\f>< /]+(?!>))

But i have some problems with some tags like 
Live example [here](https://regex101.com/r/bC6iB5/1)

Finally , when my regex will be ok, i will be ok to replace all words by
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(reg, "$1"));

thx for your help
Maybe there is an other way to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.split()` to split the `textContent` of the element. [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate array after `.split` and `appendChild` to append Element.

```js
var ELEMENT = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var text = ELEMENT.textContent;
ELEMENT.innerHTML = '';
text.split(' ').forEach(function(elem) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = elem;
  ELEMENT.appendChild(span);
});
```

```css
span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>hello i'm <b>jesus</b>
</p>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/qg15ppdn/)